# Simple loading html using Ajax with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

That is the simple code from my index.html

http://pastebin.com/d2f7UuAa

In the script part I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  

            $('document').ready(function(){
                    $("#cv").click(function(){
                            $("#div1").load("cv.html",aviso());
                    });
            });

            function aviso(){
                    alert('La solicitud ha sido procesada');
            }
    });

</script>
```

And this is in cv.html

```
<h1>&iexcl;Mi CV!</h1>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery Ajax capability to display different content loading in an asynchronic way. I've already searched here and tried this: [Dynamically load PHP within a main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826921/dynamically-load-php-within-a-main-page) but I've got no success. The function aviso() does execute although, but the content is not displayed. I know this is probably a very simple problem, but I'm stucked there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with this: `load("cv.html", function() {
  aviso();
}`

Comment: The file cv.html does exist, in the same dir as index.html

Comment: load("cv.html", function() { aviso(); } didn't make it either.

Comment: On the page, press F12, go to the console and type `$("#div1").load("cv.html")`.  What happens?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Public/Documents/zaratemarcelo/cv.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: You need to put the files on a web server - running them as local files (not localhost) won't work.  Do you have a web server running on your local machine so you *can* access it through localhost?

Comment: Ajax does not work over the file:// protocol

Comment: Now it works perfectly. Feeling like a noob ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `$('document').ready` is unnecessary <strike>and incorrect (should be without quotes)</strike>.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        $("#curriculum").click(function(){
            $("#div1").load("cv.html", aviso);
        });

        function aviso(responseText){
            alert('La solicitud ha sido procesada');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Marcelo Zárate - As Anthony Grist mentioned there's no element with an id of cv present in your HTML. I've updated the answer and changed the #cv to #curriculum

Comment: Actually, `$(document)` and `$("document")` are the same thing.  I only found that out recently myself :)

Comment: I know the second document is unnecesary, it is commented. That was one solution someone give me and didn't work, of course.

Comment: @Archer - You're right, just tested that and it works. Didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

There's no element with an `id` of `cv` present in your HTML that I can see. Did you instead mean this link?

```
<li><a href="#" id="curriculum">Curr&iacute;culum Vitae</a></li>
```

If so, your jQuery code should be:

```
$("#curriculum").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("cv.html", aviso);
});
```

Or you could change the value of the `id` attribute on the `<a>` element.

Comment: Yeah, that's because I thought of some kind of conflict with the id name, I tried last minute. But didn't worked before, when the names matched. Still doesn't.